# use current job start in JdbcPagingItemRead

Tags: spring-batch

I have ETL what run on scheduled time. I need to implement in reader where clause and use current job start. I try using JobContex, StepContex but wasn't sucessful.
From step I'm able to get previusJobStartTime, but can't get currentJobStartTime
My reader:

```
public class EtlUpdateReader extends JdbcPagingItemReader {

public EtlUpdateReader(DataSource dataSource,
                       EtlUpdateMapper rowMapper,
                       String dataObject,
                       String sortKey,
                       String object,
                       Date previousJobStartTime,
                       Date currentJobStartTime
) throws Exception{

    OraclePagingQueryProvider oraclePagingQueryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT * ");
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM " + dataObject);
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause("CREATE_DT  BETWEEN " + previousJobStartTime + " AND " + currentJobStartTime);
    oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(Collections.singletonMap(sortKey, Order.ASCENDING));

    this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    this.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
    this.setQueryProvider(oraclePagingQueryProvider);
    this.afterPropertiesSet();
  }
}
```

my step:

```
    public Step stepETL(String object) throws Exception {
    Date previousJob = getJobExplorer().getLastJobExecution(getJobExplorer().getLastJobInstance(jobName)).getStartTime();
    
    String currentDT = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    log.info("start {} step: {}", object, currentDT);
    Step toDo = stepBuilderFactory
            .get("step" + object)
            .listener(new StepListener())
            .<EtlUpdates, Data>chunk(batchSize)
            .reader(etlReader(object))
            .listener(new ETLReaderListener())
            .processor(processor())
            .listener(new ETLProcessorListener())
            .writer(apiWriter())
            .build();
    return toDo;
}
```

When stepBuilderFactory run, job don't have yet jobId and create time.

I have implement JobListener and it's sending to context required data, but this is after step is build.

my jobListener:

```
public class JobListener implements JobExecutionListener {
  @Override
  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    long jobId = jobExecution.getJobId();
    Date currentJobStart = jobExecution.getStartTime();
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("jobId", jobId);
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("currentJobStart", currentJobStart);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
  }
}
```

So how to modify step on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the reader step-scoped, otherwise it will be eagerly created at configuration time and can't access the runtime information you are looking for (In fact, the job hasn't started yet at that point in time).

When the reader is step-scoped, it is created at runtime and the job should have been started. This makes it possible to bind context attributes lately in the batch artifacts, see [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/step/late-binding.html).

Comment: thanks for answer. but not sure if this will help me. I'm running scheduled job, so I'm not using beans.